# Multiple hard drive backups

Tags: windows, hard-drive, backup

I work for a small IT company and we have been trying to find a piece of software that will run backups of the machines we intake to our server. We are currently using Acronis 2009 to backup disks. We like it because we can browse the backups using Windows Explorer. I was wondering if anyone knew of a updated program that will allow disk backups to network storage, file browsing the backup through Windows Explorer, restoring full disk or selected files, working quickly and efficiently?

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest rewording the question asking how to do something, as opposed to "waht program to do x", to avoid this from being closed

Comment: You can use for example a newer version of Acronis or Norton Ghost. In my personal environment i like Acronis - but the 2010 version had problems with Windows 8 laptops at our site.

Comment: The current version of Acronis allows you to do this.

Answer (score 1):

My company found [Macrium Reflect](http://www.macrium.com/). It has a [free version](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx), and a commercial version. It does the cloning, imaging, restoring to new HDDs, and the ability to mount images

Comment: Do you mean with "free version" the 30-days trial?

Comment: No, there is a full FREE version, just does not support Server installs, and is not meant for commercial use. We bought the $60 version for our office

Comment: Are you sure? At the website i only see version for private or business use which cost money.

Comment: I'll find the link when I get into the office

Comment: @Offler Updated answer with link

Comment: @Luke - Acronis allows for restoration on different away.  Macrium Reflect offers no versions and is more expensive for the same feature set as Acronis.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean?